# Deploy XML file and load it

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have created an XML file in my solution path. My solution has multiple projects (one of them is a service), now some of these projects need to refer to the XML file

1. When I try and use

   ```
   XDocument configXML = new XDocument.Load("Config.xml");
   ```

I get an error

> Cannot find symbol 'Load'

I am using System.Xml.Linq

1. Because I was unable to get around problem 1, i tried

   ```
   XElement rootElement = XElement.Load("Config.xml");
   ```

this worked, but when I run the program, i get an error:

> Unable to find the xml file

since it is searching in the ../Release folder, who can I copy the xml file to the release/debug/deployed folders?

Need some assistance!

Comment: You have `new XDocument.Load(...` shouldn't that just be `XDocument.Load(...`?

Comment: Check path to your Config.xml

Comment: Where the file is initially located?

Comment: And what the question is? How to copy file from solution to a folder on build? Or what?

Comment: @abatishchev, basically you are right, how can I add the xml file into the dependency of the project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx) is a static method, you don't need an instance:

```
XDocument configXML = XDocument.Load("Config.xml");
```

If you want the Config.xml file to be automatically copied to the output directory you could select it in the solution explorer and set its Copy to Output Directory property:

[image]

Comment: Good catch, this is the problem when you move from Java to .NET and after a long gap! Any help on the 2nd problem?

Comment: @livingtolearn, it's not quite clear what your second problem is. If the XML file is not located in the same folder as the executable you could specify a relative or absolute path to it: `XDocument configXML = XDocument.Load("foo/bar/Config.xml");`. And if you want to automatically copy the Config.xml file to the output folder you could set its `Copy to Output Directory` property in the Properties Window. I have updated my answer.

Comment: The xml file in the 'Solution Items' folder and in there it does not give me an option to 'Copy to Output Directory', so what is the work-around?

Comment: @livingtolearn, click on the XML file in solution explorer and then `F4` to display the properties window.

Comment: Nop, that's exactly what I had done 1st, now I moved the files inside a project and now I get that option. I guess its fine, some restrictions, not sure what they are.

Answer (score 2):

Select the file in Solution Explorer, and set the file's "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy if newer" or "Always" and Build Action to "None"

Answer (score 0):

As Nick has pointed out in comment to the question, you should not use new keyword while calling `XDocument.Load` static method.

Hence

```
XDocument configXML = XDocument.Load("Config.xml");
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

Use Post Build event to copy your file to Release folder each time you successfully built the project 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx